# Predicting column vector from SPD matrices

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensor

I am trying to predict a patient's fluxes which is a [24x29] matrix. I have this data set of 1802 patient's fluxes which I then transformed all of them to a Symmetric Positive Definite (SPD) matrix of size [24x24]. I am then able to use the geomstats Python package to find the geodesic path and distance between patient's fluxes. Hence, I am able to find the geodesic distance between all patients. Say for example, I take 2 patients which are SPD matrices and take a stepwise linear approximation method eg. 10 steps, I am able to find the corresponding SPD matrices in each step taken.

My task is to be able to predict the [24x29] matrix in each step.

So, to recap, I have 1802 [24x29] matrices which are mapped to 1802 [24x24] SPD matrices. And say suppose I choose any 2 SPD matrices and take a stepwise approach to go towards the other, I want to trace the SPD in each step back to the [24x29] matrix.

I am quite new to predictive modelling.

```
print(rows)
rows=np.array(rows)

print(b)
b=np.array(b)

print(slay)
slay=np.array(slay)

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

num_samples = 1000
input_dim = 24

column_vectors = rows

spd_matrices = b

# Generate dataset

X = b
Y = rows

# Define a simple neural network model

model = models.Sequential(\[
layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(1802,)),
layers.Dense(1802, activation='linear'),
\])

# Compile the model

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

# Evaluate the model

loss = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print(f"Final Loss: {loss}")

# Test the model

test_matrices = slay
predicted_vectors = model.predict(test_matrices)

# Verify the result

for i in range(10):
print(f"Original Vector:\\n{column_vectors\[i\]}")
print(f"Reconstructed Vector:\\n{predicted_vectors\[i\]}\\n")
```